# Select text value from only one object using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a product page with different products listed arranged in list format what I am trying to achieve is that if I click on first product it will give an alert with just a product name, similarly for product 2 only name should of product2 should be in alert box. So far what I have done is giving product name and the prices in alert to. Please help

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".nosto-product-list-item a").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(this).attr("target");
    var text = $(this).text();      
    $(this).click(function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        alert(text); 
        setTimeout(function() { 
            window.open(href,(!target?"_self":target));
        },300);
    });
});

});
</script>
<li class="nosto-product-list-item">

  <a class="nosto-li-link" href="#">

    <div class="nosto-product-image-link">
      <img class="nosto-product-image" src="images/product.jpg" alt="" title="">
    </div>


    <div class="nosto-product-info">
      <span class="nosto-product-name" id="nosto-product-name">Product Name </span>

      <div class="nosto-price">
          <span class="nosto-product-price nosto-old-price" id="222">229.00</span>
          <span class="nosto-product-price nosto-current-price">171.75</span>
                  </div>

    </div>

    </a><a class="nosto-button" href="#">Buy Now</a>


</li>
<li class="nosto-product-list-item">

  <a class="nosto-li-link" href="product1.php">

    <div class="nosto-product-image-link">
      <img class="nosto-product-image" src="images/product2.jpg" alt="" title="">
    </div>


    <div class="nosto-product-info">
      <span class="nosto-product-name">Product 2 Name</span>

      <div class="nosto-price">
                      <span class="nosto-product-price nosto-old-price">159.00</span>
          <span class="nosto-product-price nosto-current-price">111.30</span>
                  </div>

    </div>

    </a><a class="nosto-button" href="#">Buys Now</a>


</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R5kVp/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here 'this' refers to the anchor and $(this).text() will include all of the text of all the elements inside anchor.

To select only the name, select the element containing the name only. Like Ehsan Sajjad said

```
var text = $(this).find('.nosto-product-name').text();
```

I also dont see any point in using .each() and then register a handler inside. Also $(".nosto-product-list-item a") would select any anchor inside an element with that class. Instead you could have used

```
$(".nosto-li-link").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(this).attr("target");
    var text = $(this).find('.nosto-product-name').text();      
    alert(text); 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        window.open(href,(!target?"_self":target));
    },300);
});
```

Comment: You got a typo in there `$(this)..find(`

Comment: thanks. typo fixed. If your issue is solved now, you can mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be like this.
This would also help to keep html semantic. Add a class to each of the product anchors.
Lets say we add class nosto-product-item.
Then use this:

```
$(".nosto-product-item").click(function(){
     alert($(this).text()); 
});
```

Comment: Yes but my issue is that I have multiple products under same page which is using parent object as "nosto-product-list-item"